# Dynamically Add A TextView - Android

Tags: android, textview

How can I dynamically add a TextView to this? The commented out code doesn't work.

```
public class myTextSwitcher extends Activity {

    private TextView myText;
    public myTextSwitcher(String string){

        //myText = new TextView(this);
        //myText.setText("My Text");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're creating a text view and setting its value but you're not specifying where and how it should be displayed. Your myText object needs to have a container of some sort which will make it visible.

What you're trying to do is dynamically layout a view. See here for a [good starter article](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/130521-android-part-iii-dynamic-layouts/). From the article:

```
// This is where and how the view is used
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText("Dynamic layouts ftw!");
ll.addView(tv);

// this part is where the containers get "wired" together
ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
sv.addView(ll);
```

Comment: I'd also check to see that you want to dynamically layout a view. Since you are starting with Android you probably want to look into doing layouts by XML first. Dynamic layouts are not the place for a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you shouldn't be adding it in the constructor, non-default constructors are pretty much useless for an `Activity`. Finally, you are correctly creating a new `TextView` but you are not adding it anywhere. Get ahold of some `layout` in your content view (probably with `findViewById`), and call `layout.addView(myText)` with it.

Comment: Is it necessary to provide `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` for the textview object `mytext` ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the your text view to the activity using `setContentView(myText);`

make this

```
myText = new TextView(this);
myText.setText("foo");
setContentView(myText);
```

Answer (score 0):

in oncreate() method

```
    final TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
    tv1.setText("Hii Folks");
    tv1.setTextSize(14);
    tv1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lin);
   ll.addView(tv1);
```

Your activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/lin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
</LinearLayout>
```