# How to programmatically set textview-s and their properties?

Tags: android, textview, tablelayout

I'm programmatically populating a tablelayout in a scrollview with tablerow-s. In the tablerows I am putting the data in textviews.
Now my questyon is how to programmatically(in java) set textviews like this:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/tab"
    android:layout_weight="0.4"
    android:minWidth="80dp"
/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="81dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/tab"
/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/tab"
/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:gravity="center"
    style="@style/tab"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
/>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the end I did it like this:

```
TextView tvID = new TextView(this);
    tvID.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(w_id, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tvID.setPadding(5, 0, 0, 0);
    tvID.setTextSize(11);
    tvID.setText(sharedIDArt);
artikliVrstica.addView(tvID);
```

```
TextView tvNazArt = new TextView(this);
    TableRow.LayoutParams tvNazArtParms = new TableRow.LayoutParams(w_naz, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.4f);
        tvNazArtParms.setMargins(5, 0, 0, 0);
    tvNazArt.setLayoutParams(tvNazArtParms);
    tvNazArt.setTextAppearance(this, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large);
    tvNazArt.setText(NazivArt);
artikliVrstica.addView(tvNazArt);
```

```
TextView tvKol = new TextView(this);
    TableRow.LayoutParams tvKolParms = new TableRow.LayoutParams(w_kol, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.3f);
        tvKolParms.setMargins(5, 0, 0, 0);
    tvKol.setLayoutParams(tvKolParms);
    tvKol.setTextAppearance(this, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large);
    tvKol.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
    tvKol.setText(kolicina);
artikliVrstica.addView(tvKol);
```

```
TextView tvCena = new TextView(this);
    TableRow.LayoutParams tvCenaParms = new TableRow.LayoutParams(w_cen, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.3f);
        tvCenaParms.setMargins(5, 0, 10, 0);
    tvCena.setLayoutParams(tvCenaParms);
    tvCena.setTextAppearance(this, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large);
    tvCena.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
    tvCena.setText(cena);
artikliVrstica.addView(tvCena);
```

```
TextView tvIzbris = new TextView(this);
    TableRow.LayoutParams tvIzbrParms = new TableRow.LayoutParams((w_izb-10), TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        tvIzbrParms.setMargins(10, 0, 5, 0);
    tvIzbris.setLayoutParams(tvIzbrParms);
    tvIzbris.setPadding(0, 7, 10, 7);
    tvIzbris.setTextAppearance(this, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large);
    tvIzbris.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);
    tvIzbris.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    tvIzbris.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    tvIzbris.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    tvIzbris.setText("-");
artikliVrstica.addView(tvIzbris);
```

In the "w_*" variabiles is stored the size of the "table header cels"...

Answer (score 1):

Try this ,it may help

```
    TextView view = new TextView(this);
    view.setText("example textview ");
   //adding layout properties 
    view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
   // add the textview to the parentLayout
    parentLayout.addView(view);
```

Related Links :
[Dynamically add textViews to a linearLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918320/dynamically-add-textviews-to-a-linearlayout)

[how to generate dynamic textview in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727771/how-to-generate-dynamic-textview-in-android)

[Dynamically Add A TextView - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354034/dynamically-add-a-textview-android)